# how to add 'show/hide content' option in a webpage in html?

Tags: javascript

though there are many codes available, but i want the simplest and shortest code for an option for show/hide content.( it would be good if the text 'show/hide' can be replaced by an image for the same or by a button)

Comment: If you accept answers to some of your other questions, you may get a better response.

Comment: To accept an answer, click the checkmark beside it. FYI.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an element with `id="myElem"`, you can do:

```
elem=document.getElementById("myElem");
elem.style.display = "none";
```

and to show it:

```
elem.style.display = "";
```

Comment: `elem.style.display = "";` is better because it will inherit from the default stylesheet and you don't have to worry about inline vs block vs inline-block

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a library dependency - jquery can achieved this with

```
$("#myelm").toggle();
```